# Why I can't scroll my ListBox

Tags: windows-phone-7

Anyone know why I can't scroll my ListBox with Grid? 
Ony what I found is add this property:
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
but in my app this doesn't work

this is my xaml code:

```
    <ListBox Height="776" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxHeight="776"  Margin="11,12,0,0" Name="listBox1" Width="469">
        <ListBox>
            <Grid >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="200" Grid.Row="0" Source="/a;component/texture.png" />
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="200" Grid.Row="1" Source="/a;component/texture.png" />
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="200" Grid.Row="2" Source="/a;component/texture.png" />
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="200" Grid.Row="3" Source="/a;component/texture.png" />
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="200" Grid.Row="4" Source="/a;component/texture.png" />
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="200" Grid.Row="5" Source="/a;component/texture.png" />
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="200" Grid.Row="6" Source="/a;component/texture.png" />
                <Image Grid.Column="1" Width="200" Grid.Row="0" Source="/a;component/texture.png" />
                </Grid>
        </ListBox>
    </ListBox>
```

Thanks for any advice ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `listboxes` wrapped together. It seems like what you really want is a `ScrollViewer`.

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="11,12,0,0" Name="listBox1" Width="469">
            <Grid >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="200" Grid.Row="0" Source="/a;component/texture.png" />
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="200" Grid.Row="1" Source="/a;component/texture.png" />
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="200" Grid.Row="2" Source="/a;component/texture.png" />
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="200" Grid.Row="3" Source="/a;component/texture.png" />
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="200" Grid.Row="4" Source="/a;component/texture.png" />
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="200" Grid.Row="5" Source="/a;component/texture.png" />
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="200" Grid.Row="6" Source="/a;component/texture.png" />
                <Image Grid.Column="1" Width="200" Grid.Row="0" Source="/a;component/texture.png" />
                </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Listbox does have a ScrollViewer built-in; however some may choose to wrap a ListBox inside a ScrollViewer for smoother scrolling. And I would use an ItemTemplate inside the Listbox. These links should help:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202907(v=VS.92).aspx
- [Listbox inside ScrollViewer height calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639098/listbox-inside-scrollviewer-height-calculations)
- [DataBound ListBox and Button inside a ScrollViewer/StackPanel construct, with Button appearing below end of ListBox content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582059/databound-listbox-and-button-inside-a-scrollviewer-stackpanel-construct-with-bu)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add the scrollviewer property to the inner listbox also.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for advice.
That didn't work because I had two listboxes wrapped together. Thanks willmel;)

This should look like:

```
    <ListBox Height="776" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxHeight="776"  Margin="11,12,0,0" Name="listBox1" Width="469">
            <Grid >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="200" Grid.Row="0" Source="/a;component/texture.png" />
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="200" Grid.Row="1" Source="/a;component/texture.png" />
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="200" Grid.Row="2" Source="/a;component/texture.png" />
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="200" Grid.Row="3" Source="/a;component/texture.png" />
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="200" Grid.Row="4" Source="/a;component/texture.png" />
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="200" Grid.Row="5" Source="/a;component/texture.png" />
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="200" Grid.Row="6" Source="/a;component/texture.png" />
                <Image Grid.Column="1" Width="200" Grid.Row="0" Source="/a;component/texture.png" />
                </Grid>
    </ListBox>
```